# XCode 4 Core Data hang

Tags: core-data, xcode4, freeze

XCode4 is hanging on me when I go and save an .xcdatamodel after changing anything.  Is anyone else having this issue?  I've got everything up to date and am using 10.6.7. It seems like others on a different board re-downloaded 3 and are using that.  Don't want to go there if need be.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If Xcode is hanging, it's a bug and should be reported via http://bugreporter.apple.com so they can fix it.